# tableView:heightForHeaderInSection message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my flow having redirection v1 to v2 to v3 to v4.... v9. Now when I reached to v9 and that time I receive remote notification that time "DidReceiveRemoteNotificationWillCall". Now I do redirection to V10 Screen from notification, that time my application crash with `[V5 tableView:heightForHeaderInSection]` message sent to deallocated instance.

Now I don't know, how to called tableview method of V5 screen. I have not been able to find what is the main issue.

Nothing big and complicated in my code:

```
 todayAppointmentScreen=[[Confirmation3VC alloc]initWithNibName:@"Confirmation3VC" bundle:nil];
                        [self.navControl pushViewController:currentLocationScreen animated:YES];
```

I'm just redirecting like above code.

Comment: show some code sir

Comment: @AhmedDaou please check my updated question. And I'm using `self.navcontrol` when I'm redirecting when receiving notification. And `self.navigationcontaoller` used when Redirection code from uiviewcontroller

Comment: All VC in single navigationController? You can enable Zombies to detect exact instance which was deallocated.

Comment: @TimurBernikowich: I got this error by Zombies.

Comment: Can you put breakpoint this method? Check who is calling it. And check viewWillAppear of v5. Do you have same notification registration in v5?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add following lines to your vc5

```
- (void) dealloc {
      self.tableView.delegate = nil; 
      self.tableView.datasource = nil; 
}
```